# does OPENAI_API_VERSION correspond to a particular model version

Tags: python, openai-api

I wonder if setting `OPENAI_API_VERSION` as an environment variable would enable me to consistently query the same model.

https://github.com/openai/openai-python/blob/v0.27.8/openai/__init__.py#L51-L54

Comment: That's what it appears to do.